Identifying the Cause of a Survival Curve Display Issue
I am conducting a survival analysis (using Cox proportional hazards regression) in R. My overall sample has a ~10% mortality rate, but the Kaplan-Meier survival curves that are derived from my analysis appear to show a ~40-50% drop in survival, with a precipitous decline around the 4-year mark. This does not reflect the pattern of times to death in the actual dataset, but I am unsure what could be causing this discrepancy... Does anyone have an idea?

The code for generating the survival curves is below:
# Define the strata for the plot
strata <- expand.grid(
  depression_level = levels(complete_cases_all$depression_level),
  sex = levels(complete_cases_all$sex)
  )
rownames(strata) <- letters[1:nrow(strata)]

# Define the average participant
average_participant <- expand.grid(
  depression_level = levels(complete_cases_all$depression_level),
  sex = levels(complete_cases_all$sex),
  calendar_year = median(complete_cases_all$calendar_year),
  age = median(complete_cases_all$age),
  education_level = median(complete_cases_all$education_level),
  employment = "Competitively Employed",
  marital_status = "Single",
  rehab_payor_primary_type = "Non-Medicaid",
  func_score = median(complete_cases_all$func_score),
  mental_health_tx_hx = "Denied any history of mental health treatment",
  psych_hosp_hx = "Denied any history of psychiatric hospitalization",
  problematic_substance_use = "No",
  suicide_attempt_hx = "Denied any history of suicide attempt"
  )
rownames(average_participant) <- letters[1:nrow(average_participant)]

# Fit the survival model
cxsf <- survfit(model_5, newdata = average_participant, conf.type = "none")
surv_cxsf <- surv_summary(cxsf, data = complete_cases_all) |>  # Summarize the survival model
  tibble()
m_newdat <- average_participant[as.character(surv_cxsf$strata), ]  # Match new data with survival summary strata

gg.surv.model5 <- surv_model_5 |>
  ggsurvplot_df(
    surv.geom = geom_line,
    color = "depression_level",
    xlab = "Time After X (years)",
    ylab = "Survival Probability",
    legend = c(0.175, 0.175),
    conf.int = FALSE,
    censor = FALSE,
    surv.scale = "percent",
    break.time.by = 1,
    xlim = c(0, 5), # Limit x-axis to 5 years
    ylim = c(crop, 1),
    palette = c("#90cbf9", "#2196f3", "#114b7a"),
    ggtheme = theme_classic(),
  ) +
  labs(linetype = "Sex", color = "Depression Level")

The data are based on a longitudinal dataset with follow-up interviews conducted at 1 and 4 years after the initial study enrollment date. Dates of censorship were determined by the last available follow-up interview date for each censored participant, and dates of death were determined by the date listed in each decedent's official death certificate. Time 0 corresponds to the study enrollment date for each participant, with follow-up through the subsequent 5 years.
I've inspected the dataset for an abnormal count of decedents with deaths after the 4-year mark, but there appeared to be a reasonable frequency of deaths during this interval (~23% of the total deaths occurred between 4 and 5 years). There are also plenty of censored participants with censorship dates during this period. I also ensured that my times to death are based on dates rather than (whole-number) follow-up intervals. Finally, I made sure that the censored participants are also contributing data within the 4-5-year window.

@SolarMike I'll try that!

Censoring is an obvious candidate. For example, if only 10 participants survive to 4 years, on death will result in a 10% drop in survival. It’s the number at risk at time t, not the number at risk at time 0 that defines the drop in survival following a death. I agree this is better asked at CrossValidated.

@Limey Thanks for the added context. I just figured the overall survival probability would end up around 90% if the total mortality rate was 10%. Am I wrong to think that?
